# Dataframe to numpy array to plot polygons with matplotlib

Tags: dataframe, matplotlib, polygon

I've got coordinates in a dataframe that I can export as this numpy array.
I'd like to draw polygons on a picture by using matplotlib out of those coordinnates (x1 = 1006, y2 = 302 ; x2 = 106, y2 = 302 and so on)
I'm not sure I should do it directly from a numpy array or if I have to convert it to a different format?

```
[[1006  302 1065  302 1065  314 1006  314]
 [1006  323 1065  323 1065  335 1006  335]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to reshape your array into `n` x `2` where `n` is the number of vertices:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

a = np.array([[1006, 302, 1065, 302, 1065, 314 ,1006, 314],
              [1006, 323, 1065, 323, 1065, 335, 1006, 335]])

polygons = [Polygon(a[i].reshape(-1,2)) for i in range(len(a))]

_,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(polygons,fc='none',ec='r'))
ax.set_xlim(1000,1100)
ax.set_ylim(300,350)
```

[image]